# how to navigate the previous page by clicking previous button in android?

Tags: java, android

I create application by seeing quote from sqlite database.
    each quote display in one page when i click next button its move to next quotes ,
    in last quote when i pressed previous button it is move to very first quote, i want move to previous quote please

```
public class ResultsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private DuasDatasource dbHelper;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    Button btnPrevious,btnNext,btnHome,btnIndex;
    final Context ctx=this;
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.resultsinfo);
    dbHelper = new DuasDatasource(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    btnPrevious= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnIndex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIndex);
    btnIndex.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHome);      
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(this);


     displayListView();

}
private void displayListView() {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value =  null;
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("dua_id");
    }

    Cursor cur = dbHelper.fetchById(value);
    displayData(cur);

    setBtnVisible();

}

 `private void setBtnVisible(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String value =  null;
     Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAll();
        int curCount=cursor.getCount();

    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("dua_id");
    }
    if(Integer.parseInt(value)==1){
        btnPrevious.setVisibility(View.GONE);           
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(Integer.parseInt(value)>1 && Integer.parseInt(value)<curCount){
        btnPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(Integer.parseInt(value)==curCount){
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }   
}`
```

Comment: btnNext and btnPrevious code?

Comment: show your onclicklistener impl for btn previous ?

Comment: You don't need to cast to Button to setOnClickListener and setVisibility, just sayin.

Comment: where is your OnClickListener..?? you need String value should be decrement....

Answer (score 0):

override the function `onBackPressed`

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//      super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and then you can put what event you want.

Good Luck.